# Push all numbers in square brackets into array

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried/searched a lot but couldn't solve my problem. I guess it is quite easy and some one can give me a hint/link.

I want to transfer all numbers in square brackets [123] on my webpage to a variable like this:  var all_sources_url = "123,123,123,123," and attach the variable to a link.

Webpage example:

```
<h1>Text</h1>
<p>For a generative propagation, seeds must be harvested in winter from high quality sites in the nearby area or a site with similar growing conditions [682, 683].</p>
<p>Germination is increased by frost. Germination rates about 80 % can be achieved with good seeds [684].</p>
```

Link example

```
<h1>Link</h1>
<p><a href="" target="_blank" id="all_sources">List of all cited literarure</a></p>
```

JS trial (if the variable would look like described above it would work, but constructing the variable does not work.)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var all_sources_url;       
   $.each(($("p").html().match(/\[(.+?)\]/g)), function( index, value){
    all_sources_url += value;
   });
  $("#all_sources").attr("href", "quellen.php?id=" + all_sources_url + "&name=literature");
 });
 </script>
```

Thank you very much for your help!
To

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var all_sources_url = [];       
   $.each(($("p").html().match(/\[(.+?)\]/g)), function( index, value){
    all_sources_url.push(value.replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
   });
  $("#all_sources").attr("href", "quellen.php?id=" + all_sources_url.join(",") + "&name=literature");
 });
 </script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Whoever has marked this down, kindly state the problem with this code so that it is good for everyone's learning... thanks!